# Как вывести id Telegram

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

Как вывести id у канала в Telegram.

```
for mes in msgs:
        with TelegramClient(Phone, api_id, api_hash) as client:
            result = client(functions.messages.GetAllChatsRequest(
                except_ids=[42]
            ))
            print(result.stringify('id')) 
            был такой еще вариант
            print(result.stringify(['channel', 'id']))
            #my_file = open('test.txt', 'a')
            #my_file.write(result.stringify()+'\n')
            #print("TEST")
            time.sleep(6)
```

Тут просто выводится вся информация о канале.

Ошибка

print(result.stringify('id'))
TypeError: stringify() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
Channel(
        id=1499501182,
        title='Тут было название канала',
        photo=ChatPhoto(
            photo_small=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(
                volume_id=200006400504,
                local_id=390002
            ),
            photo_big=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(
                volume_id=200006400504,
                local_id=390004
            ),
            dc_id=2
        ),
        date=datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 14, 11, 15, 37, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
        version=0,
        creator=False,
        left=False,
        broadcast=True,
        verified=False,
        megagroup=False,
        restricted=False,
        signatures=False,
        min=False,
        scam=False,
        has_link=False,
        has_geo=False,
        slowmode_enabled=False,
        access_hash=6797022806759780742,
        username='Тут было название канала',
        restriction_reason=[
        ],
        admin_rights=None,
        banned_rights=None,
        default_banned_rights=None,
        participants_count=None
    ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте `result.to_dict()['chats'][0]['id']`
Вы можете просто ответ преобразовать в словарь и обращаться к его элементам по ключу